# Where am I(the unlucky)?

Tags: riddle, cipher, steganography

I am very unlucky. Can you guess where I am?

> Forever do I find myself
>       victim of the most
>       queer and cruel
>       ruses. The devil's
>       jest will forever
>       nag me and me.
>       Yet until my
>       Xebec crashes back
>       perpetually into the sea,
>       endlessly I'll fight the
>       notorious fumes of the unlucky.
>       Puzzling but not perfect,
>       I'll leave this puzzle be.

Comment: Are you sure it's a cipher? Looks like a riddle to me.

Comment: The last line is wrong. Writing up an answer now

Comment: Oops forgot to add that. But yes, it is a cipher. :)

Comment: @manshu it is indeed a cipher although it is also sort of a riddle. see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> In a **sidewalk crack** (definitely unlucky)

Taking the first letters gives

> fvqrjnyxpenpi

Which rot13 is

> sidewalkcracv

Or more clearly

> Sidewalk crac (v)

The last two lines suggest that this isn't quite perfect, and indeed the last letter isn't correct and should be a 'k'

Comment: I did that on purpose as the last two lines suggest. I thought it would be even more obvious if I had two words that start with X.

Comment: @ClangorousChimera ah ok. I'll add that then

Comment: @ClangorousChimera oh, and welcome to puzzling! :)

Comment: Why did you think it should be rot13?

Comment: @Forklift it is the most common cipher, and the fact it had many very low letters in the alphabet (v-z) indicates that it is likely a rot cipher between 10 and 16, because those letters usually appear in the ciphertext of those